# Would using Interfolio affect the credibility of letters?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, united-states, recommendation-letter

One of my referees asks me to use [Interfolio](https://www.interfolio.com/) so that she does not have to upload her recommendation letter multiple times. Basically, she uploads the letter to Interfolio, which generates a random email address for it like `send.Smith.1234567ABC@interfolio.com`. After I input that as the email of the recommender in the online application system, some Interfolio employees will receive the letter request from the school and upload the letter on her behalf.

The thing is, this is not an institutional email address, and many schools suggest against the use of non-institutional email addresses like `@gmail.com`. I wonder if using Interfolio would affect the credibility of the letter, or create additional delay since the schools need to contact the professor with her institutional email address to verify the authenticity of her letter (which completely defeats the purpose of using Interfolio in the first place)? Another concern of mine is confidentiality. There is nothing stopping me from instructing the Interfolio staff to send a copy of the letter to myself, which gives schools another reason not to trust the letter.

Comment: I suspect the professor has used Interfolio to that end in the past, and has made positive experiences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Among universities I am familiar with, using interfolio is considered normal.  Graduate admissions or hiring committees will not draw any meaningful conclusion from the fact that you used interfolio.

A few might require you to use it for a job application.